# Proving a lemma on the Span and linearly independent family

Tags: linear-algebra

I am writing a proof in linear algebra. 
In order to conclude I need a small lemma, which I think is true :

Nota :  $S$ is finite iff there exists a generating set of $S$ which is finite

> Let $L$ be a linearly independent family of a finite vector space $S$. 
>   Let G be a generating set of $S$, containing  $s$ elements and $x$ an element of $G$.
>
> Then $\operatorname{card}(L)\leq s$ (finite dimension theorem)
>
> let $\mathscr{D}=\{M\in \mathfrak{P}(S) | L\subset M \subset G \wedge M \text{ is linearly independent}\}$
>
> and $\mathscr{E}=\{\operatorname{card}(x), x \in \mathscr{D}\}$
>   . 
>   Let $m=\max(\mathscr{E})$ and $B$ an element of $\mathscr{E}$ with $\operatorname{card}(B)=m$
>
> Then $B$ is a generating set

**Proof**

$\mathscr{D}$ is not empty as $L \subset L$

$m$ exists as $s$ is an upper bound of $\mathscr{E}$ and $\operatorname{card}(L) \in \mathscr{E}$

Let $m=0$, $G=\varnothing$, then $S=\{0\}$ and $B=\varnothing$ is a generating set

Otherwise

...

Can anyone help me filling the blanks?

Thanks,

T.D

Comment: What do you call a *generator* of the vector space?

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Generator_of_Vector_Space

Comment: question corrected sorry

Comment: What is $n$, exactly? And $\operatorname{card}(B)$, since $\mathscr E$ is a set of cardinals?

Comment: sorry n should be an m there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't $S=\mathbb R^{2}, B=\{(1,0)\}, G=S, x=(0,1)$ a counterexample?

Comment: my lemma as it stands is wrong as I didnt copy the full text, mb.